# How can I improve my solution for getting unknown text between tags?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm very at Python and BeautifulSoup and trying to up my game. Let's say this is my HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
<h4>Title 1</h4>
Text I want is here
<br /> # random break tags inserted throughout
<br />
More text I want here
<br />
yet more text I want
<h4>Title 2</h4>
More text here, but I do not want it
<br />
<ul> # More HTML that I do not want</ul>
</div> # End container div
```

My expected output is the text between the two H4 tags:

```
Text I want is here
More text I want here
yet more text I want
```

But I don't know in advance what this text will say or how much of it there will be. There might be only one line, or there might be several paragraphs. It is not tagged with anything: no p tags, no id, nothing. The only thing I know about it is that it will appear between those two H4 tags.

At the moment, what I'm doing is working backward from the second H4 tag by using .previous_siblings to get everything up to the container div.

```py
text = soup.find('div', class_ = 'container').find_next('h4', text = 'Title 2')
text = text.previous_siblings
text_list = []
for line in text:
    text_list.append(line)
text_list.reverse()
full_text = ' '.join([str(line) for line in text_list])
text = full_text.strip().replace('<h4>Title 1</h4>', '').replace('<br />'>, '')
```

This gives me the content I want, but it also gives me a lot more that I don't want, plus it gives it to me backwards, which is why I need to use reverse(). Then I end up having to strip out a lot of stuff using replace().

What I don't like about this is that since my end result is a list, I'm finding it hard to clean up the output. I can't use get_text() on a list. In my real-life version of this I have about ten instances of replace() and it's still not getting rid of everything.

Is there a more elegant way for me to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the previous siblings for [`NavigableString`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=findall#navigablestring)s.

For example:

```
from bs4 import NavigableString

text = soup.find('div', class_ = 'container').find_next('h4', text = 'Title 2')
text = text.previous_siblings
text_list = [t for t in text if type(t) == NavigableString]
```

`text_list` will look like:

```
>>> text_list
[u'\nyet more text I want\n', u'\nMore text I want here\n', u'\n', u'\nText I want is here\n', u'\n']
```

You can also filter out `\n`'s:

```
text_list = [t for t in text if type(t) == NavigableString and t != '\n']
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solution: Use `.find_next_siblings()` with `text=True` (that will find only `NavigableString` nodes in the tree). Then each iteration check, if previous `<h4>` is correct one:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<div class="container">
<h4>Title 1</h4>
Text I want is here
<br />
<br />
More text I want here
<br />
yet more text I want
<h4>Title 2</h4>
More text here, but I do not want it
<br />
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

out = []
first_h4 = soup.find('h4')
for t in first_h4.find_next_siblings(text=True):
    if t.find_previous('h4') != first_h4:
        break
    elif t.strip():
        out.append(t.strip())

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['Text I want is here', 'More text I want here', 'yet more text I want']
```